# About error handling method in case of data inconsistency of firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a video posting app using firebase and flutter.
When the data design of the video posting application is constructed as follows.

```
firestore
'movies'(collection)
   |
    --'fooaaaa-bbbb-cccc.mp4'(document_id)
   |       |
   |        --'uid:'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',(field)
   |
    --'foodddd-eeee-ffff.mp4'(document_id)
           |
            --'uid:'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',(field)


'users'(collection)
   |
    --'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'(document_id)
   |       |
   |        --'displayName':'John'(field)
   |
    --'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'(document_id)
           |
            --'displayName':'emily'(field)

And I save the video file in cloud_storage.
```

In order to display the uploader's name for each video item on the video list display page,

first get the documents of the movies collection, then get the displayName of the uploader,

```
"displayName":(await instance.collection('users').doc(tempData['uid']).get())
                .data()['displayName'],
```

I'm getting the displayName with the above code.

For example, if I move to the video list page with only the'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'document in the users collection deleted without deleting the movies document corresponding to the user'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb' in the movies collection,
the LoadingIndigator will rotate endlessly. The video list cannot be displayed continuously.

This issue doesn't occur if I never delete the documents in the users collection.
However, I don't think this is a countermeasure because data may be lost due to erroneous operation or accident.

What are some possible specific solutions to this problem?

The way that comes to mind is
(1) Prepare the isExistUser field in the document in the movies collection as shown below, and set true when generating the document.
(2) Set false in the isExistUser field of corresponding documents in the movies collection When a document in the users collection is deleted.
(3) When retrieving the video list, filter by the isExistUser field to prevent inquiries about non-existent documents in the users collection.

The above method comes to my mind, is there anything wrong with this method?
Please let me know if there is a better way, such as "usually do this".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use a dedicated function to get the `displayName` that can check if the users exists or not. So you don't need to resrtcuture your database. The code would look like this:

```dart
class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;

  GetUserName(this.documentId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("User Deleted!");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text(data['displayName']);
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

It's quite complicated and I had a hard time dealing with it, but thanks to your answer, I think I was able to deal with it well.

I'm really thankful to you.